# Override clone function in javascript

Tags: javascript, clone

I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833851 to clone a function so that I can override it. For example:

```
Function.prototype.clone = function() {
    var that = this;
    var temp = function temporary() { return that.apply(this, arguments); };
    for(var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp[key] = this[key];
        }
    }
    return temp;
};

window.capture_list = [];
window.handler_clone = window.YAHOO.handleData.clone();

window.YAHOO.handleData = function(oRequest, oResponse, oData){
    window.capture_list.push( {'oRequest': oRequest, 'oResponse': oResponse, 'oData': oData} );
    return window.handler_clone( oRequest, oResponse, oData );
};
```

This appears to achieve the task, but I get a "[Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530)" in practice.

It seems like the clone method I'm using is recursing into itself somehow... I think I'm misunderstanding something about this clone implementation due to my limited js experience.

Any thoughts on where this recursion is, or how to better implement the clone for overriding?  I'm really just trying to intercept the arguments passed to handler().  Thanks!

the handleData function:

```
window.YAHOO.handleData = function(oRequest, oResponse, oData) {
    if (oData == null) {
        oData = {}
    }
    oData.totalRecords = oResponse.meta.totalRecords;
    return oData
};
```

Comment: Please show us what exactly `/*do something*/` is, and which of those `f`, `g`, `f` functions you are calling how. We currently cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Btw, there's absolutely no reason to `.clone()` `f` when you are overwriting it anyway!

Comment: @#1 Thanks for your help.  I've updated my post to be more specific, although I can't give you the exact code to reproduce.  Basically, I am trying to intercept yui xhr requests.

Comment: @#2 how would I call the original f() though, from inside the override f()?

Comment: For this problem, you can (and should) in fact omit the `.clone()` completely and just do `window.handler_clone = window.YAHOO.handleData;`. However, if you can't make a demo that exhibits the error you're getting, we hardly can help you. It doesn't look like your decorator is the root of the problem. Does it even work without capturing?

Comment: You might want to try `handler_clone.call(window.YAHOO, oRequest, oResponse, oData)`

Comment: Yes, it works just fine before the cloning interceptor.  But then I get one of those runaway script error dialogs.  I figured maybe that the cloned_to_f() was calling itself after the override since I renamed the cloned_from_f()

Comment: No sane implementation should behave like that (but your decorator is a bit off). Is the source of `YAHOO.handleData` online somewhere? Regardless, what is `Object.keys(window.YAHOO.handleData)` (before you've overwritten it)?

Comment: There are no keys, i.e. "[ ]".  I've updated the post w/ the function source... hard to see where this gets recursed.

Comment: Oh indeed. And where does that function get called? What's the stack trace of your stack overflow?

Comment: I am doing this through selenium.  After I apply my interceptor code, I "call" the function by clicking a button to trigger the request.  I then do driver.execute_script( "return window.capture_list;" ) -- this is when I get "WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Maximum call stack size exceeded\n  (Session info: chrome=34.0.1847.137)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 x86_64)'"

Comment: Wow, that's not much information to work with.

Comment: Yep.  I get the same result when doing like you said with omitting the .clone() -- I need to read up on js decoration

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through this:

Clone copies `this` then applies any arguments to the original function, then iterates the keys in function (I am assuming to get the prototype properties?), then returning that back out.

It seems like you are trying to create a decorator?

In any case, I am not sure why you haven't opted to use `bind` it creates a new function with the context that is passed in.

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I knew there had to be a smarter way about this.  I'll accept your answer once I confirm.  Thanks!

Comment: Side note, I have run your prototype, it seems okay, it's probably your callback stack causing the maximum range exception.

Comment: Sorry for being such a nub... but any hints as to how I could debug the callback for this seeming recursion?  The callback is not actually my code

Comment: You can throw an exception, and log the stack, the best I can think of right now.