# What is the best way to copy but not clone a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

Given that I have declared a function in the for of `foo = function F() {}` how can I copy **but not clone** that function.
For example with the code below each time one calls the function `log()` with an argument that argument is added to the array `log.list` that list can be shown by calling the function `log.alert()`.

How can one declare a new variable `log2` that will copy the functionality of the `log` function but remain independent of it?

i.e an independent `list` will be maintained for `log` and `log2` and by calling `log2.alert()` the `log2.list` will be shown and by calling `log.alert()` the `log.list` will be shown?

```
var log = log || function F (x) {
    F.list = F.list || [];
    if (x != undefined) F.list.push(x);
    if (!F.fired) {
        F.alert = function () {
            alert (F.list.join("\n"));
        }
        F.reset = function () {
            F.list = [];
        }
    F.fired = true;
    }
}

// Demonstrate the function
log("log #1");
log("log #2");
log("log #3");
log("log #4");
log.alert();
```

Comment: If you want mutable state, why not make an object?

Comment: Functions are held by reference, which means they're never copied on assignment. I don't know what difference you see in a copy and a clone but there's no real way to fully copy a function *(Including its closure state)* unless maybe you do some `eval` ugliness.

Comment: Davin I and looking to have the functionality copied also, not just the list.  I guess I could shove in the list Object in the function in the form log("sdgh", myObject) but I was wondering how to avoid that.

Comment: squint, regarding cloning a functions here's some answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833588/javascript-clone-a-function if the function is cloned using one of the methods there then the list will not remain independent.  If the function could be copied the list would remain independent.  I was thinking of using `var log2 = Function (log.toString())` but the problem with that is that the function **F*** is wrapped in _anonymous function_.  I'll wait and see if anyone has a solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ones a bit a tricky. You've half described *factories*, which are functions that return new objects (including functions), and half described a regular constructor, which creates instances.

The crux of this question is whether or not *directly* invoking your `log` and `log2` variables is of real importance. JavaScript doesn't offer a way to meta-call non-function objects, and it even looks like ES6 `Proxies` skipped on implementing this functionality (You can only intercept invocations of functions). The only real way to invoke `log` is if it *is* a function.

You could define a factory function that returns a function with the appropriate methods attached directly to it, and encapsulate any variables you need. The overhead involved with this pattern is that you have to redefine a function and two methods *every* time you create a new 'log'.

```js
function logFactory () {
  var stack = [];
  
  function f () {
    stack.push.apply(stack, arguments);
  }
  
  f.list = stack;
  
  f.alert = function () {
    alert(stack);
  };
  
  f.reset = function () {
    while (stack.length > 0) {
      stack.pop();
    }
  };
  
  return f;
}

var log = logFactory(),
    log2 = logFactory();

log('one', 'three');
log2('two', 'four');

log.alert();
log.reset();
log2.alert();

alert('Lists are different? ' + log.list !== log2.list);
```

---

However, if you don't need to invoke the `log` object directly, you can create a normal constructor with prototype methods, and drop the overhead.

```js
function Log () {
  this.list = [];
}

Log.prototype.add = function () {
  this.list.push.apply(this.list, arguments);
};

Log.prototype.alert = function () {
  alert(this.list);
};

Log.prototype.reset = function () {
  while (this.list.length > 0) {
    this.list.pop();
  }
};

var log = new Log(),
    log2 = new Log();

log.add('one', 'three');
log2.add('two', 'four');

log.alert();
log.reset();
log2.alert();

alert('Lists are different? ' + log.list !== log2.list);
```

---

It should also be noted that in your example, the function `F` is redefining its own methods every time it is invoked to push something to the `list`. That's very undesirable.

Comment: Hi @Oka,  Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer which I think answers the question very well.  I made a small edit to my snippet which avoids the redefinition of the methods upon invoking the function.  It is a shame that people down voted my question.  I don't see what's so bad about it.  Any up votes would be appreciated.

Comment: Your named `F` function is just implementing a very strange pattern, and I would not recommend using it. `log` becomes this self constructor / pseudo-instance that gets defined, but doesn't have any properties until you invoke it for the first time. You're giving `F` and the subsequent invocations of `log` _too_ many responsibilities, that could be better delegated with a more traditional pattern.

Comment: The snippet here is part of a much larger snippet.  The main idea is to have a log function that has to be actively initiated.  This might be done either by a method `log.initiated(debug)` where `debug` is set a the beginning of the script or can be triggered by input in a UI.  When I finish the script hopefully in the next couple of days I shall post a link to it.  I would really appreciate any comments on how to improve it after I post it.  Thanks