# Javascript - Cloning a prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I would like to modifiy a prototyped function of an external library in order to execute some code before that function when it is called. I though to clone that function and then replace it by a new one like so:

Note that I am using a clone function found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833851/1914034)

**This is a simplified example:**

```
var oldFunction = anObject.aFunction.clone();
anObject.aFunction = function(a, b, c) {
    if (a > b) {
        return;
    } else {
       oldFunction(a, b, c);
    }
}

Function.prototype.clone = function() {
    var that = this;
    var temp = function temporary() { return that.apply(this, arguments); };
    for(var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp[key] = this[key];
        }
    }
    return temp;
};
```

However, doing so, the `oldFunction` seem to lose all its original reference to `this`.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to clone the function, just keep a reference to it. Or more accurately, create a copy of the function with the correct `this` binding.

```
var oldFunction = anObject.aFunction.bind(anObject);
anObject.aFunction = function(a, b, c) { ... };
```

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a copy of the given function with `this` specified by the first argument. It can also be used to bind arguments as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it with the correct this:

```
oldFunction.call(this, a, b, c);
```