# Is it necessary to have {} inside Template.bind({}) while making stories in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Recently I have started learning to react Storybook. In the below example, when I don't write `{}` in `Template.bind({})`, the Storybook will run absolutely fine without any error. But I have found that many of the people use `{}` in `Template.bind({})` while making stories.

Question: Is it necessary to have `{}` inside `Template.bind({})` while making stories in Storybook?

```
import React from 'react'
import { MyButton } from './MyButton'

export default {
    title :  'MyButton',
    component : MyButton
};

const Template = (args) => <MyButton {...args}/>

export const Primary = Template.bind()
Primary.args = {
    variant: 'primary',
    label: 'button'
}
```

Comment: I think it is necessary to add `{}` inside `Template.bind()`

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik Why do you think so? :)

Comment: It is fine to omit `thisArg` in `bind` (it will be set to be the one of executing scope) which is  irrelevant anyways because you are using arrow function that captures `this` lexically.

Answer (score 9):

No, `{}` is not necessary or important.

`.bind(thisArg)` is a method that you can call on a function to return a new function with its `this` keyword set to whatever you pass to `thisArg`. However, on an arrow function (like in your example), it doesn't matter what you pass as `thisArg`, since [`this` works differently on arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#call_apply_and_bind). Calling `.bind()` will just return a new clone of the function.

The `.bind()` method is only being used here to clone the `Template()` function. The *binding* behavior isn't really important (especially because it's an arrow function). The important part is that when you do this:

```js
export const Primary = Template.bind()
Primary.args = {
    variant: 'primary',
    label: 'button'
}
```

`Primary` gets its own `args` property. You get multiple clones of the `Template` function that don't interfere with each other.

Here's an [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6772648/8886761), which explains how to clone a function with its `.bind()` method in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

`Template.bind({})` is a waste of time/resources since it creates an object on every invocation, so basically yeah - `Template.bind()` will suffice. If no arguments are provided to bind nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Then why when I remove the `{}` it shows an error saying: `Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0.`

Comment: `function f(){} f.bind()` I don't see any errors

Comment: I get the same `Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2555)
lib.es5.d.ts(353, 22): An argument for 'thisArg' was not provided.`, but `null` or `undefined` can be used to work around it without creating new objects.