# Implement redux compose function but get RangeError

Tags: javascript, recursion, redux

I am trying to re-implement redux [compose](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.ts) function, instead of using `reduce` i use a for loop, here is my code:

```js
function compose(...funcs) {
  if (funcs.length === 0) {
    return (arg) => arg;
  }

  if (funcs.length === 1) {
    return funcs[0];
  }

  let result;
  for (let i = funcs.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    result = result
      ? (...args) => funcs[i](result(...args))
      : (...args) => funcs[i](...args);
  }

  return result;
}

// test
function fn1(x) {
  return x + 1;
}

function fn2(x) {
  return x * 10;
}

function fn3(x) {
  return x - 1;
}

console.log(compose(fn3, fn2, fn1)(10)); // 109
```

It is expected to log 109 since (10 + 1) * 10 - 1 is 109, however it gives me such error:

```js
RangeError: Maximum call stack size
```

Looks like i am doing some recursion but all i did is just a for loop, no sure where is the problem of my code?

Comment: `(...args) => funcs[i](result(...args))` this line looks suspicious.

Comment: @kiner_shah what's the problem of this line?

Comment: Not sure, but I feel calling `result` is somehow leading to recursion.

Comment: @kiner_shah right, i got the same confusion, but couldn't clearly pointing out why it may leads to infinite recursion

Comment: BTW what is that for loop supposed to do?

Comment: @kiner_shah its just my own implementation.

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Isn't there an alternative way for that logic than this?

Comment: @kiner_shah Definitely there is...The source code of compose using `reduce` to achieve the functionality. But personally i don't want to use `reduce` and the logic inside the for loop should be the same as using `reduce`(I think...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is like the below example:

```js
a = () => 2;
a = () => 3 * a();
console.log(a); 
// this prints () => 3 * a() in console
// so when you call a(), it will call 3 * a(), which will again call 3 * a() and so on
// leading to infinite recursion
```

My solution is slightly different using `bind` function based on this reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6772648/4688321.

I think `bind` creates a new copy of the function `result` and binds it to a new object. Not using `bind` leads to recursion because then the code becomes like the above example, `result` calls `result`.

```js
function compose(...funcs) {
  if (funcs.length === 0) {
    return (arg) => arg;
  }

  if (funcs.length === 1) {
    return funcs[0];
  }

  let result;
  for (let i = funcs.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (i == funcs.length - 1)
      result = (...args) => funcs[i](...args);
    else {
      let temp = result.bind({});
      result = (...args) => funcs[i](temp(...args));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// test
function fn1(x) {
  console.log("fn1");
  return x + 1;
}

function fn2(x) {
  console.log("fn2");
  return x * 10;
}

function fn3(x) {
  console.log("fn3");
  return x - 1;
}

//console.log(compose(fn3, fn2, fn1));
let ret = compose(fn3, fn2, fn1);
console.log(ret(10)); // 109
```

Comment: Cheers, i see the problem. In your first example, when declaring the `a = () => 3 * a()` here `a` actual equals `() => 2`, however right now `a` does not get executed. After call `a()`, `a` get executed but because of the above declaration, a becomes `() => 3 * a()` and leads to a infinite recursion.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to combine functions at the time of `compose`, it seems much easier to combine them at the time the resulting function is *called*:

```js
function compose(...funcs) {
  if (funcs.length === 0) {
    return (arg) => arg
  }

  return function (...args) {
    let result = funcs .at (-1) (...args)
    for (let i = funcs.length - 2; i > -1; i--) {
      result = funcs [i] (result)
    }
    return result
  }
}

// test
function fn1(x) {
  return x + 1;
}

function fn2(x) {
  return x * 10;
}

function fn3(x) {
  return x - 1;
}

console.log(compose(fn3, fn2, fn1)(10)); // 109
```

However, again, `reduce` make for a much cleaner implementation:

```js
const compose = (...fns) => (arg) => 
  fns .reduceRight ((a, fn) => fn (a), arg)
```

or if you want to allow the rightmost function to receive multiple variables, then

```js
const compose = (...fns) => (...args) => 
  fns .reduceRight ((a, fn) => [fn (...a)], args) [0]
```